# boost deadline timer my code not run concurrently

Tags: c++, timer

I am planning to use boost c++ library for my one-shot timer requirement in my project.

In my program timer is started and i want my program to continue with its execution while timer is running, but in the below code my program is blocked 
until timer expires.. is there a way to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{
    std::cout<<"timer expired...";
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;

    boost::asio::deadline_timer t1(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t1.async_wait(print);

    io.run();
    int var;

    while(1) { // i want this loop to execute while timer running....
        std::cout<<"Main execution...\n";
        std::cin>>var;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The boost documentation for [io_service.run()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) says:

> The run() function blocks until all work has finished and there are no more handlers to be dispatched, or until the io_service has been stopped.

So, as expected, calling this will wait until the timer expires, at which point there's no more work to call and `run()` returns. The idea is that you're supposed to put your other functions into boost handlers so they can be called by boost's IO system, and `run()` takes the place of your own main loop.

The alternative is polling. For your example, you would want to remove the `io.run()` call from before your loop, and place a call to [io.poll()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll/overload1.html) within your loop. (Note that there's also a [version of poll()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll/overload2.html) that can return information abouts errors.)

You'll also need to come up with a way to make your main loop stop executing if you do this; just putting the call to `io.poll()` into your loop should give you the output you're expecting, but you're still in an infinite loop.

Comment: Exit the loop when `io.poll()` returns non-zero (meaning it ran the timer), or  loop until a flag variable is set and have the completion handler `print` set that flag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `io.run()` blocks as long as there is work to be done, in this case until your timer expires. For this particular example, you could achieve what you are trying, easier IMHO by using standard C++11 library functions, for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  auto handle = std::async(
      // set this to force execution on separate thread
      std::launch::async, 
      // a simple lambda to sleep for 1 second and print smth
      []() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout<<"timer expired..." << endl;
      });

  std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
  while (1) {
    std::cout<<"Main execution..." << endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(5));                                                                                                                       
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run with:

```
→ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -pthread && ./a.out
Running
Main execution...
timer expired...
Main execution...
^C
```

Whether this applies to the rest of you application I can't know from your post, but standard thread/async capabilities have improved significantly since C++11 and it's worth giving them a try :)